# U.S. Rate Hike Prediction

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, fx, futures, forward-rate

In a recent ft.com video an analyst mentioned that markets postponed their Fed rate hike expectation from September to around November 2015 due to the CNY devaluation, based on the "shift" of some "futures" curve.

Which future rate curve predicts(reflect) rate hike expectations and please include a real-time updated link to that curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CME' Fed Fund Futures are what you are looking for.

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/30-day-federal-fund.html

On settlement day they settle at the average overnight rate set by the Fed during the contract month.